# In the tensorflow debugger -> invoke_stepper, what does `[ H ]` represent?

Tags: debugging, tensorflow

When walking through a call in the tensorflow debugger using `invoke_stepper`, the top of the display looks like this:

```
--- Node Stepper: run #1: 2 fetches; 1 feed (input:0) ----------------------------------------------------------------
| <-- --> | s
     (176 / 3492)  [  H   ] ConvBlockLarge_55/BatchNorm/batchnorm/mul/y
     (177 / 3492)  [  H   ] ConvBlockLarge_55/BatchNorm/batchnorm/mul                                               UP
  -->(178 / 3492)  [  H   ] ConvBlockLarge_55/BatchNorm/batchnorm/mul_2                                             
     (179 / 3492)  [      ] ConvBlockLarge_55/BatchNorm/batchnorm/sub                                               
     (180 / 3492)  [      ] ConvBlockLarge_55_1/convolution/filter
```

What does the `[  H   ]` represent? I see it in video tutorials like this:

https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/02/debug-tensorflow-models-with-tfdbg.html

But I can't find any documentation to describe what the `H` flag is, and what other flags exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The legend was hiding 3000 lines down at the bottom of the list:

```
Legend:                                                                                            
  P - Placeholder                                                                                  
  U - Unfeedable                                                                                   
  H - Already continued-to; Tensor handle available from output slot(s)                            
  I - Unfeedable                                                                                   
  O - Has overriding (injected) tensor value                                                       
  D - Dirty variable: Variable already updated this node stepper.
```